# Catch Google Assistant's responses in Android App

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, google-voice

How can I catch a response by Google Assistant in Android application?
For example, I said "Ok Google", "London weather today" then I want to catch and process this answer in android app.

Maybe... Something like Broadcast Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API available for Android developers to capture the audio or direct transcription of what a user said. For a way to interact for the Google Assistant to interact with your app, you should look into [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview) although it may not fit your exact use case.